# How to Display Meta Box for custom post type in home,archive,plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I use WordPress Meta Box for the custom post type
how to appear in the home, archive, recent posts plugins, and other pages

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to show meta box's value of custom post type in front end. You can show those on anywhere. You just need to know two things the id of Post and the meta_key.

Following function can get you the values of the meta of any post.

get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true );

The meta key is the key which is identifier of meta field.

You simply echo those values wherever you want to show them up.